# How to remove empty entries of an array recursively?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, is-empty, array-filter

I need to remove empty entries on multilevel arrays. For now I can remove entries with empty sub-arrays, but not empty arrays... confused, so do I... I think the code will help to explain better.

```
/**
 * 
 * This function remove empty entries on arrays
 * @param array $array
 */
function removeEmptysFromArray($array) {
    
    $filtered = array_filter($array, 'removeEmptyItems');
    return $filtered;
}

/**
 * 
 * This is a Callback function to use in array_filter()
 * @param array $item
 */
function removeEmptyItems($item) {
    
    if (is_array($item)) {
        return array_filter($item, 'removeEmptyItems');
    }
 
    if (!empty($item)) {
        return true;  
    }
}


$raw = array(
    'firstname' => 'Foo',
    'lastname'  => 'Bar',
    'nickname' => '',
    'birthdate' => array( 
        'day'   => '',
        'month' => '',
        'year'  => '',
    ),
    'likes' => array(
        'cars'  => array('Subaru Impreza WRX STi', 'Mitsubishi Evo', 'Nissan GTR'),
        'bikes' => array(),
    ),
);

print_r(removeEmptysFromArray($raw));
```

This code will remove `nickname`, `birthdate` but is not removing `bikes` that have an empty array.

My question is... How to remove the `bikes` entry?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<?php
function array_remove_empty($haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $haystack[$key] = array_remove_empty($haystack[$key]);
        }

        if (empty($haystack[$key])) {
            unset($haystack[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $haystack;
}

$raw = array(
    'firstname' => 'Foo',
    'lastname'  => 'Bar',
    'nickname' => '',
    'birthdate' => array(
        'day'   => '',
        'month' => '',
        'year'  => '',
    ),
    'likes' => array(
        'cars'  => array('Subaru Impreza WRX STi', 'Mitsubishi Evo', 'Nissan GTR'),
        'bikes' => array(),
    ),
);

print_r(array_remove_empty($raw));
```

Comment: Thanks, just used it. One addition: if you want to remove "whitespaced" strings in array values also, then add a one little "elseif" clause: if (is_array($value)) {
            $haystack[$key] = array_remove_empty($haystack[$key]);
            } elseif(is_string($haystack[$key])) {
            $haystack[$key] = trim($value);
        }   that way array(array(" ", ' ')) will be returned as empty also.

Comment: Always use \_\_FUNCTION__ in recursive calls to make your function portable.

Comment: @ThanhTrung , he's calling array_remove_empty from inside array_remove_empty. If he were to rename the function, there would no longer be an array_remove_empty function to call. If the internal call was done by assigning `$fn = __FUNCTION__` and then calling $fn, it would work whatever the function was named. An alternative of course is *be careful when you rename functions and ensure you replaced all the **proper** function name's occurrences*. Especially if you rename a function to avoid name clashes, when the function will still exist, **but as a completely different function**.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution, it will remove exactly specified list of empty values recursively:

```
/**
 * Remove elements from array by exact values list recursively
 *
 * @param array $haystack
 * @param array $values
 *
 * @return array
 */
function array_remove_by_values(array $haystack, array $values)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $haystack[$key] = array_remove_by_values($haystack[$key], $values);
        }

        if (in_array($haystack[$key], $values, true)) {
            unset($haystack[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $haystack;
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
$clean = array_remove_by_values($raw, ['', null, []]);
```

Note, it removes empty sub arrays if you pass `[]` as one of values.

Answer (score 1):

```
array_filter(explode('/', '/home/teste sdsd/   /'), 'trim');
//Result
[
     1 => "home",
     2 => "teste sdsd",
]

//-----------
array_filter(explode('/', '/home/teste sdsd/   /'), 'strlen')
//Result
  [
     1 => "home",
     2 => "teste sdsd",
     3 => "   ",
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should solve your problem.

```
$retArray =array_filter($array, arrayFilter);

function arrayFilter($array) {
     if(!empty($array)) {
         return array_filter($array);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursively clear multidimensional array of empty'ish items:

```
final class ArrayCleaner
{
    public static function clean(array $value): array
    {
        foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
            if (\is_array($v)) {
                $value[$k] = self::clean($v);

                if (0 == \count($value[$k])) {
                    unset($value[$k]);
                }
            } elseif (empty($v)) {
                unset($value[$k]);
            }
        }

        return $value;
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
final class ArrayCleanerTest
{
    public function testItCleans(): void
    {
        $input = [
            'empty_string_to_remove' => '',
            'empty_int_to_remove' => 0,
            'empty_string_number_to_remove' => '0',
            'value_to_keep' => 5,
            'empty_array_to_remove' => [],
            'empty_array_of_empty_arrays_to_remove' => [
                'one' => [],
                'two' => [],
                'three' => [false, null, '0'],
            ],
            'array_to_keep_1' => [
                'value' => 1,
            ],
            'array_to_keep_2' => [
                'empty_to_remove' => [],
                'array_to_keep' => ['yes'],
            ],
        ];

        $expected = [
            'value_to_keep' => 5,
            'array_to_keep_1' => [
                'value' => 1,
            ],
            'array_to_keep_2' => [
                'array_to_keep' => ['yes'],
            ],
        ];

        $this->assertEquals($expected, ArrayCleaner::clean($input));
    }
}
```

[Working proof of concept at 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/9Zt7A)

Answer (score 0):

`array_filter()` and `empty()` may be safe to leverage for the asker's sample input, but they are not reliable for public general use.  These native functions will treat all "falsey" values as filterable/empty.  See [the documentation for `empty()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) for details on its greedy determination of emptiness.

I recommend explicitly checking (data type specifically) for empty string strings if that is the intent.  This way you don't inadvertently destroy meaningful data.  I am choosing to declare `$value` as a reference to avoid iterating a copy of the array -- this allows me to mutate/overwrite array data with `$value` instead of the more verbose `$array[$key]` (when not using `unset()`.

Code: ([Demo with an assortment of falsey values](https://3v4l.org/gRg1b))

```
function recursivelyRemoveEmpties(array $array): array
{
    foreach ($array as $key => &$value) {  // modify by reference to affect original array
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = recursivelyRemoveEmpties($value);
            if (!$value) {  // if the array is empty
                unset($array[$key]);
            }
            continue;
        }
        if ($value === '') { // add additional qualifying conditions here only
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $array;
}

var_export(recursivelyRemoveEmpties($raw));
```

<sub>*Note that this script is not designed to accommodate objects in the data payload.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

My function:

```
function removeEmptyItems($item)
{
    if (is_array($item)) {
        $item = array_filter($item, 'removeEmptyItems');
    }
    return !empty($item);
}

$nonEmpty = array_filter($raw, 'removeEmptyItems');
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple and elegant solution based on recursive function. Dont liked any solution from the prev. answers. Removes empty sub arrays/sub values:

```
/**
 * Clean array from empty values
 * @param $array
 * @return array|mixed
 */
function array_filter_recursive($array){
    if (!is_array($array)) return $array;
    foreach ( $array as $key=>$item){
        if (is_array($item))
            $array[$key] = array_filter_recursive($item);
    }
    return array_filter($array);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want array_filter to work recursively, you'll need to make sure that the subsequent calls may edit the deeper nested items of the array. Short: You'll need to pass it by reference:

```
function removeEmptyItems(&$item) {
    if (is_array($item) && $item) {
        $item = array_filter(&$item, 'removeEmptyItems');
    }

    return !!$item;
}
```