# Delete all empty sub-array in array

Tags: php, arrays

How can I filter array and delete all empty elements.
I need to remove empty elements from an array, including arrays in arrays.

From that array:

```
$array = [
    'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
    'user_agent' => 'dkdkdk',
    '_id' => 'fjjfjf',
    'user' => [
        'longName' => '', 
        'shortName' => '',
        'username' => [
            'a' => 'b',
            'c' => ''
            ]
    ],
    'dsd' => [
        'zz' => [
            'dd' => [
                'ff' => ''
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ],
    'dsddd' => '',
    'vcv' => null,
    'aavx' => 0
];
```

I want get:

```
$array = [
    'ip' => '127.0.0.1',
    'user_agent' => 'dkdkdk',
    '_id' => 'fjjfjf',
    'user' => [
        'username' => [
            'a' => 'b',
            ]
    ],
    'aavx' => 0
];
```

I try use array_filter but it remove only not array keys

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795671/1427878 - modify accordingly, so that the filtering happens by your specific criterion.

Comment: (And please pay a bit more attention when showing example data. What you have currently shown, is not even syntactically valid.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP - How to remove empty entries of an array recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7696548/php-how-to-remove-empty-entries-of-an-array-recursively)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all empty arrays or keys, you will have to iterate recursively and pass value by reference to the subsequent recursive calls to make sure you edit the same copy of the subarray. Now, you can just have empty checks and unset them.

```
function removeEmptyArrays(&$array){
    foreach($array as $key => &$value){
        if(is_array($value)) removeEmptyArrays($value);
        if(is_array($value) && count($value) == 0 || is_null($value) || is_string($value) && strlen($value) == 0) unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
```

**Demo:** https://3v4l.org/XDJdD