# Remove key value pairs from an nested associative array where the value is null or " " or []

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I've the following array:

```
$variables = [
    "id" => "discountCodeID",
    "test" => null,
    "codeDiscount" => [
        "code" => "discountCode",
        "title" => null,
        "startsAt" => "discountStartsAt",
        "endsAt" => "",
        "usageLimit" => "discountUsageLimit",
        "usesPerOrderLimit" => "discountUsesPerOrderLimit",
        "customerBuys" => [
            "value" => [],
            "items" => "discountCustomerBuysItems"
        ],
        "customerGets" => [
            "value" => "discountCustomerGetsValue",
            "items" => "discountCustomerGetsItems"
        ],
        "customerSelection" => "",
        "appliesOncePerCustomer" => "discountAppliesOncePerCustomer"
    ]
];
```

Now I wanna remove all the key value pairs where the value is `null` or `""` or `[]`.
But the problem is using simple array filter doesn't work because of the nested arrays. So I took the following approach:

```
foreach ($variables as $key => $value) {
    if (is_null($value) || $value === '' || (is_array($value) && empty($value))) {
        unset($variables[$key]);
    } elseif (is_array($value)) {
        $variables[$key] = removeEmptyValuesFromArray($value);
    }
}

function removeEmptyValuesFromArray($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_null($value) || $value === '' || (is_array($value) && empty($value))) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $array[$key] = removeEmptyValuesFromArray($value);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

print_r($variables);
```

Well this code works but the problem is the array might become lot larger with more levels of nested arrays. And certainly this wouldn't be a good solution in that case.

So what approach would you take in this situation?

Arigato Gozaimasu!

Comment: I would look at recursion. [List of tutorials](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=php+recursion+tutorial&t=newext&atb=v362-1&ia=web)

Comment: Why wouldn't this be a good solution? What's your concern?

Comment: @shingo I'm concerned about the execution time as I'm using two foreach loops.

Comment: Two foreach loops maybe are a bit redundant, but I cannot see any performance issues here, any approaches have to walk through all the elements just like you did.

Comment: If you have many, many levels of sub-arrays (for example, more than 100 levels deep), then you may encounter issues with the recursive approach due to the size of your memory stack.  If this is your problem, then you could look at doing a depth-first traversal of your array instead.

Comment: Can you please tell me more? Honestly I don't have any idea about this "depth-first traversal". Did some research but couldn't figure how it works.

Comment: @WakilAhmed - I added an alternative answer, highlighting the 'depth-first' traversal.  See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to cater for the edge case where all the elements of a sub-array are removed (and so the sub-array itself should also be removed), I would suggest a slight reordering of the tests in your recursive function:

```
function removeEmptyValuesFromArray($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $value = removeEmptyValuesFromArray($value);
            $array[$key] = $value;
        }
        if (is_null($value) || $value === '' || (is_array($value) && empty($value))) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: Um, wait.  This answer of yours is a depth-first technique too.  Right, Rob?  (also effectively demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75944409/2943403))

Comment: @mickmackusa - yes, correct.  Although this one uses recursion, the other answer I wrote does not

Answer (score 1):

You already have a recursion in your function.

So you don't need the first `foreach` loop outside of it. You can simplify your code as follows:

```php
function removeEmptyValuesFromArray($array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            unset($array[$key]);
        } elseif (is_array($value)) {
            $array[$key] = removeEmptyValuesFromArray($value);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}

$variables = removeEmptyValuesFromArray($variables);
```

Also, note that you can replace `is_null($value) || $value === '' || (is_array($value) && empty($value))` by `empty($value)`

Comment: A sensible answer, but be careful with `empty()` since it will be true for any falsey value (including `false` or `0`) so these will also be excluded.

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: Be warned that his answer will not remove elements which contain empty elements. Proof: https://3v4l.org/G86r8

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_filter_recursive(array $array): array
{
  return array_map(
    static fn($value) => is_array($value) ? array_filter_recursive($value) : $value,
    array_filter($array)
  );
}
```

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)

Comment: Be warned that his answer will not remove elements which contain empty elements. Proof: https://3v4l.org/8lLhI

Answer (score 1):

If you have an array structure that is many levels deep (for example, a 100 or more), then a recursive approach may lead to a stack overflow (each time a function recurses, it adds the calling context to the stack, ready for retrieval once that call has finished).  If you are in this situation, then a 'depth-first' traversal may be more predictable.

Rather than iterate over all the elements in a level, then descend, a 'depth-first' traversal aims to go to the deepest elements first.  You can do this without recursion using something like this:

We start by setting up a dynamic list of nodes to check.  Each node will have a couple of properties: a 'scope' which is a reference to the array that contains the value, a 'key' which is the key within the scope, and (optionally) a flag which indicates if we should descend or not.  We initialise the list with the elements of our input array `$a`.

```
$nodesToCheck = [];
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $nodesToCheck[] = [
        'scope' => &$a,
        'key' => $k,
    ];
}
```

Now we enter the main loop, which starts by popping the last node off the end of our `$nodesToCheck` array.  Note that we also add to the `$nodesToCheck` array as we discover further sub-arrays, and by using `array_pop` means we always examine the deepest node seen so far.

```
while ($node = array_pop($nodesToCheck)) {
    $value = $node['scope'][$node['key']];  // for convenience
    if (is_array($value)) {
        if (empty($value)) {
            // an empty array - remove this element from the parent scope array
            unset($node['scope'][$node['key']]);
        } else {
            // a non-empty array - if we haven't been this way before,
            // then re-add it and all its child elements
            // to the $nodesToCheck array
            if (empty($node['done'])) {
                $node['done'] = true;
                $nodesToCheck[] = $node;
                foreach ($value as $k => $v) {
                    $nodesToCheck[] = [
                        'scope' => &$node['scope'][$node['key']],
                        'key' => $k,
                    ];
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        // a non-array value - if is is null or '' then remove it
        if (is_null($value) || $value === '') {
            unset($node['scope'][$node['key']]);
        }
    }
}
```

This kind of approach should work however many sub-arrays you have in your input array.